# Pythonの2次元配列の片方のリストに値を追加したい。

Tags: python, python3, array

## 実現したいこと

Pythonの2次元配列の片方のリストに値を追加したいです。例えば、

```
list1=[0.43,0.52,0.56,0.74,0.62]
```

と配列が与えられている時に、配列から1つ要素を持ってきて、その要素を100倍した後2次元配列に入れたいのですが、この時片方には100倍した値で決まっていますが、もう片方は決まっていません。

```
temporary = orbit[0]
temporary2 = abs(temporary*100)
list2[int(temporary2)][]=temporary #ここの[]の方は空でここに追加したい。
```

例えば,

```
temporary = 0.43
temporary2 = abs(0.43*100)=43
list2[43][]=temporary #ここの[]の方は空でここに追加したい
```

となります。図に表すと
[image: 配列list2]

となります。numpyのappendを使おうとしましたが上手くいきません。ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

行数が決まっていないとは言っても最大で `len(list1)` なのですから、以下の様にしてもよろしいかと思います。

```py
import numpy as np

scale = 100
list1 = [0.43, 0.52, 0.56, 0.74, 0.62]
list2 = np.zeros((len(list1), scale))

for i, v in enumerate(list1):
  list2[i, int(abs(v)*scale)] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

要素を逆にしたところ、望む結果が得られました。(scaleは出力の関係上1/10にしています。)

```
import numpy as np

scale = 10
list1 = [0.43, 0.434, 0.432, 0.74, 0.62]
list2 = np.zeros((scale,len(list1)))

for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    list2[int(abs(v)*scale),i] = v

for i in list2:
    print(i)

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0.43  0.434 0.432 0.    0.   ]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0.   0.   0.   0.   0.62]
[0.   0.   0.   0.74 0.  ]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```